# How does one copy an arbitrary block of text in Sublime Text 3's Vintage mode?

Tags: vim, sublimetext3

I'm using Vintage mode (i.e. vi-style interface) in Sublime Text 3.

I'm trying to copy an arbitrary block of text.  In regular Vim, the way I do this is:

1. Position the cursor at one end of the block.
2. Set a vi *mark* at that position, e.g. with `mx` ("set mark `x` here").
3. Position the cursor at the other end of the block.
4. Yank all text between the current position and mark `x` into the vi clipboard with `` y`x ``.

However, when I do this, it only seems to yank the current line into the clipboard, as if I had typed `yy` instead of `` y`x ``.

`` `x `` by itself works as normal (i.e. moves the cursor to mark `x`).  But `` y`x `` does not.

As a result I find myself frequently using shift-arrow keys to highlight arbitrary text, which is OK, but is a mental shift I'd like to avoid.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sublime's Vintage mode simply doesn't support it, unfortunately.

If you'd like a better Vim support, try the `Vintageous` package. It indeed supports the `` y`x `` you are looking for (just tried it).